# LLVM generated vector math assembly segfaulting

Tags: segmentation-fault, llvm, x86-64, vectorization

The following LLVM function takes three pointers to arrays of five doubles and calculates C = A*B + C:

```
define void @my_vector_math(double* %A1, double* %B2, double* %C3) {
entry:
  %0 = bitcast double* %C3 to <5 x double>*
  %1 = load <5 x double>* %0, align 64
  %2 = bitcast double* %B2 to <5 x double>*
  %3 = load <5 x double>* %2, align 64
  %4 = bitcast double* %A1 to <5 x double>*
  %5 = load <5 x double>* %4, align 64
  %6 = fmul <5 x double> %3, %5
  %7 = fadd <5 x double> %1, %6
  store <5 x double> %7, <5 x double>* %0, align 64
  ret void
}
```

It compiles down to the following assembly on my machine (64 bit Ubuntu 13.10, LLVM 3.4):

```
  30:   c5 fb 10 42 20          vmovsd 0x20(%rdx),%xmm0
  35:   c5 fb 10 4e 20          vmovsd 0x20(%rsi),%xmm1
  3a:   c5 fd 28 16             vmovapd (%rsi),%ymm2
  3e:   c5 fb 10 5f 20          vmovsd 0x20(%rdi),%xmm3
  43:   c5 f5 59 cb             vmulpd %ymm3,%ymm1,%ymm1
  47:   c5 ed 59 17             vmulpd (%rdi),%ymm2,%ymm2
  4b:   c5 fd 58 c1             vaddpd %ymm1,%ymm0,%ymm0
  4f:   c5 ed 58 0a             vaddpd (%rdx),%ymm2,%ymm1
  53:   c5 fd 29 0a             vmovapd %ymm1,(%rdx)
  57:   c5 f9 13 42 20          vmovlpd %xmm0,0x20(%rdx)
  5c:   c5 f8 77                vzeroupper
  5f:   c3                      retq
```

Called with arrays of size 5 it always segfaults, but it does sometimes produce correct results with oversized arrays:

```
int main() {
  double A[] = {1,1,1,1,1};
  double B[] = {2,2,2,2,2};
  double C[] = {3,3,3,3,3};
  my_vector_math(A, B, C); // Segfaults
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%f\n",C[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out why this is happening, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit:

The LLVM IR without any optimization passes:

```
define void @my_vector_math(double* %A1, double* %B2, double* %C3) {
entry:
  %a = alloca <5 x double>
  %b = alloca <5 x double>
  %c = alloca <5 x double>
  %C = alloca double*
  %B = alloca double*
  %A = alloca double*
  store double* %A1, double** %A
  store double* %B2, double** %B
  store double* %C3, double** %C
  %C4 = load double** %C
  %0 = bitcast double* %C4 to <5 x double>*
  %1 = load <5 x double>* %0
  store <5 x double> %1, <5 x double>* %c
  %B5 = load double** %B
  %2 = bitcast double* %B5 to <5 x double>*
  %3 = load <5 x double>* %2
  store <5 x double> %3, <5 x double>* %b
  %A6 = load double** %A
  %4 = bitcast double* %A6 to <5 x double>*
  %5 = load <5 x double>* %4
  store <5 x double> %5, <5 x double>* %a
  %c7 = load <5 x double>* %c
  %a8 = load <5 x double>* %a
  %b9 = load <5 x double>* %b
  %6 = fmul <5 x double> %a8, %b9
  %7 = fadd <5 x double> %c7, %6
  %C10 = load double** %C
  %8 = bitcast double* %C10 to <5 x double>*
  store <5 x double> %7, <5 x double>* %8
  ret void
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your IR claims that the arrays of doubles have 64-byte alignment, which causes the compiler to generate an aligned load.  You probably intended to specify 8-byte alignment instead (the natural alignment of a double on many platforms).

Comment: Changing the alignment to 8 bytes for the loads and stores did the trick. I wasn't specifying the alignment manually; the "Instruction Combining" optimisation pass was doing that.


The PNaCL people seem to have added their own pass to fix this: https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/pnacl-llvm/+/master/lib/Transforms/NaCl/FixVectorLoadStoreAlignment.cpp


Wonder if it's a bug that should be reported upstream?


This might also be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065800/alignment-of-vectors-in-llvms-amd64-output

Comment: I suspect that you are specifying the alignment but don't realize that you're doing so; how are those vectors declared, and how do you convert to them from array of double?

Comment: I've added the pre-optimization pass IR I generate via the C API to the original post. I don't think I'm specifying any alignment at all.

Comment: IIRC the natural alignment of `<5 x double>` is either 64 (= 5*8 rounded up to a power of two) or the platform's maximum supported alignment, whichever is less.  So `load <5 x double>*` assumes 64B alignment unless you add an explicit `align`.